# Invalid postback or callback argument, posting to other page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

**Background:**

I'm working on a really old project where the header is a UserControl and tags, links, buttons and everything on it are added with output.Write. Its a really big file and need to keep it working as it is.

**Feature:**

I'm creating a div that ask for the password when a user click a link to go to a more secure side, i do an ajax request and if the password is valid it returns a token, i set this token into a hidden field and click on a button to submit that token to other page.

**The Problem:**

I'm generating with the output.Write the Form, the inputs and the buttons and when I try to do the submit i get the Invalid postback or callback argument.

this is how i generate it:

```
        mystringbuilder.Append("<div id='blackout' style='display: none'>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("</div>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("<div id='adminPassword' style='display: none;' class='popupcont'>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("   <a href='#' onclick=""return closeDiv('adminPassword','',0);"" class=""pclose""></a>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("  <br />")
        mystringbuilder.Append("Password: <input type='password' name='txtPassword' id='txtPassword'/><br>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("<button type='button' id='btnLogin'> Login </button>")
        mystringbuilder.Append(String.Format(" <input style='display:none' type='text' name='hidUsername' id='hidUsername' value='{0}'/>", User.UserName))
        mystringbuilder.Append(" <FORM action='/tokenLogin.aspx' method='post'>")
        mystringbuilder.Append(" <input style='display:none' type='text' name='hidAuthToken' id='hidAuthToken'/>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("<button type='submit' style='display:none' id='btnTransfer'> Transfer </button>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("</FORM>")
        mystringbuilder.Append("</div>")
```

I tried adding this but i still get the same result:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("hidAuthToken")

 Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("btnTransfer")
```

Is there any workaround i can try? i cant disable the validation because this is in the header and i would be disabling it for all pages.

Comment: Why are you using a display none text input instead of an actual `hidden` input?

Comment: @Pow-Ian thats a really good question... no idea why that is like that and i didint noticed until now, i changed it.

Comment: my only guess is it could have been from debugging. Maybe whomever put it in there originally wanted to see the token and make sure it worked, and then instead of changing it, just hid it.

Comment: Is this the only form on the page?  ASP.NET Webforms do not play well with more than 1 form.  If that isn't the problem, use Chrome or Firebug to look at the POST data and see if one of the fields is being sent but isn't registered for event validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of work around is going to open you to vulnerabilities but my favorite is the phantom button.

You place an ASP button on the page anywhere that you want and set its display to none. Then you hijack its post back so that you always have a valid post back event. I do this all the time for dynamically created buttons in grids.

My presumption is that your login button does the ajax call and then triggers a click event of the submit button. So that is how I am going to word this answer.

so if you placed:

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="btnPhantom" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Visible="false" />
```

somwhere on your page, then you would modify your code like this:

```
mystringbuilder.Append(string.format"<input type='button' style='display:none' id='btnTransfer' value='Transfer' onclick='javascript: {0}'/>", Page.ClientScript.getPostBackEventReference(btnPhantom,null) )
```

Then in your page load you need to watch for the event of the phantom button:

```
C#

String tEventTarget = Request("__EVENTTARGET).ToString();
if(tEventTarget == btnPhantom.UniqueID){
    //read input from request and redirect
}

VB

Dim tEventTarget as String = Request("__EVENTTARGET).ToString

If tEventTarget = btnPhantom.UniqueID Then
   //read input from request and redirect 
End IF
```

I do this all the time for dynamic controls the page has no awareness of. It is a bit of a hack and like I said it may not be the most secure method of doing this, but then storing a plain text authorization token in a text box is not that secure either ;).

Comment: I found your solution really helpful but im getting downvotes on the question im not sure why, so I might delete the hole question.

Comment: Not sure what the down-votes are about. I up-voted it. Lets see what happens. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: I think it was a bug or something weird, i had 5 downvotes but now just 1.